# UiApplication is not able to maintain its state

Tags: blackberry

I am developing an application to do the following things.

1. Tracks the Incoming/Outgoing Call.
2. If user attends to the call, after disconnected the call a Screen will pop-up.(User Have to fill some info and content will save in (Sqlite) database)

Now what I am doing is :-

1. First Make different entry point (autostartup) & this is the Entry-point of the application. (logic is working fine)
2. Implement Phone-listener that tracks Incoming/Outgoing Calls (logic is working fine)
3. When a call is disconnected, detail Screen will pop-up, User can fill up the screen. (logic is working fine)
4. But the Problem is when user Receives/Do calls and return back to the application, application isn't able to maintain variable states (like File Connections, Global variables that uses in application) they all become reset. This issue I am getting only on the Incoming/Outgoing Call time.

   - I used Run-time persistence storage but its not working in case of records insertion into the database.
   - I reinitialize the Database class but it's not working at all.

Please let me know, Why I am getting this issue.

Answer (score 2):

"application can't able to maintain variable states (like File Connections , Global variables that uses in application ) they all become reset"

I presume that you are trying to maintain these 'global' variables as 'static' variables.  Remember that static variables are only global to the same Application instance.  In this case, the Phone Listener is invoked under a different application - the phone application - and so these variables are different to those that you see in your application.

To resolve this, I recommend doing two things:

a) Use RuntimeStore to provide a place to store shared (global) variables:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-a-singleton-using-the-RuntimeStore/ta-p/442854

b) Have your listeners do as little as possible, use global events to pass the required information back to your application in your Application's context:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Global-Events-and-Global-Event-Listeners/ta-p/444814

But perhaps I have not understood your problem clearly, if not, please clarify.

Comment: ..I follwed your advise "Remember that static variables are only global to the same Application instance. ... so these variables are different to those that you see in your application." ... Before your answer I am creating two entry point of the application (one is Auto startup for (Background Phone Listener) and another one is main entry point for UI)  ..I just wanted to know that is their any requirement of using Background application combine with UI application.. Because PhoneListener works fine in Ui application also.